# Having confusion in understanding module structure in rust

Tags: rust

I am facing some confusion to understand the module's structure in rust.
As the rust-book mentioned [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#modules-cheat-sheet)

> In the crate root file, you can declare new modules;

So, as rust tells us that crate root is `src/main.rs` and `src/lib.rs`.

1. In the above mentioned link the author of the book created the module named `garden` in `garden.rs` file which is not crate root, how???
2. For declaring submodules the rust books tells us this:

> In any file other than the crate root, you can declare submodules.

Does this means to declare a submodule we need to create a folder in `src` folder and inside of that folder we need to create file for submodules? As describes here:

```
backyard
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── garden
    │   └── vegetables.rs
    ├── garden.rs
    └── main.rs
```

Comment: Yes, `mod garden;` would be in `main.rs` and `mod vegetable;` would be in `garden.rs`

Comment: each file that starts with `pub mod <nameOfModule>`, is a module. If you request it by another module, it will become its submodule.

Comment: @99problems no, the fact that a file contains a line like `mod foo;` or `pub mod bar;` at the start or anywhere else does _not_ make that file into a module. A file `foo.rs` is a module if there is some _other_ file that is already a module or a crate root and if that _other_ file contains a `mod foo;` line (with or without `pub`).

Answer (score 2):

> In the above mentioned link the author of the book created the module named garden in garden.rs file which is not crate root, how???

I think what is confusing you here is what “in a file” means.

The key thing to understand about the Rust module system is that a module is always *declared in* some Rust source code somewhere (whether it is the crate root or a module), and that is *not* the source code of the *contents* of the module. So, specifically:

1. The module `garden` is *declared in* the crate root file (such as `src/lib.rs`) by `mod garden;`. This means the module is an item inside the crate root.
2. The compiler takes this as instruction to look for `src/garden.rs` or `src/garden/mod.rs`.
3. Whatever source code the compiler finds in that file becomes the *contents* of the module known as `crate::garden`.

In general, modules are always declared by *their parent*, not themselves.

> Does this means to declare a submodule we need to create a folder in src folder and inside of that folder we need to create file for submodules?

By “submodule” here, the authors just mean “module that is in another module, rather than being in the crate root”. Given that: yes, submodules go in folders inside `src`.

In the example, *because* `vegetables` is a submodule of `garden` (meaning that it was declared in `garden.rs`),

- its module path is `crate::garden::vegetables`, and
- its source code is found at `src/garden/vegetables.rs`.